# Jquery / PhP / Joomla Select one of two comboboxes does not get updated

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, drop-down-menu

I am making a Joomla component wich has 3 `comboboxes/selects` on the page. One with languages and 2 with subjects. If you change the language the other two get filled with the same data (the subjects in the selected language) the name of the `selectbox` are different but otherwise the same.

I get an error for one of the subject boxes (hence the url gets red), but there is no logic in wich one will give an error. In Firebug i get the HTML back for the one without the other and this one gets updated but the other one gives nothing back.

If i right click in firebug on the one that gave the error, and do "send again" it will load fine. Is their a timing problem?

The change event of the **language selectbox:**

```
jQuery('#cmbldcoi_ldlink_language').bind('change', function() {

    var cmbLangID = jQuery('#cmbldcoi_ldlink_language').val();

    if (cmbLangID  !=0) {

        getSubjectCmb_lang(cmbLangID, 'cmbldcoi_ldlink_subjects', '#ldlinksubjects');  
    }
});
```

Function that requests the php file to create the html for the select:

```
function getSubjectCmb_lang(langID, cmbName, DivWhereIn) {
    var xdate = new Date().getTime();

     var url = 'index.php?option=com_ldadmin&view=ldadmin&format=raw&task=getcmbsubj_lang&langid=' + langID + '&cmbname=' + cmbName + '&'+ xdate;

     jQuery(DivWhereIn).load(url, function(){

     });
}
```

And in the php file there is a connection made to the database to ge the information to build the selectbox. I use a function for this that is okay because it makes al my selectboxes. The only place where there are problems with select boxes is on the pages that has 2 selects that need to change when a third one changed. My guess it is somewhere in the Jquery where this goes wrong. And i think it has to do with  timing. But i am open for all sugestions.

Thanx.

**UPDATE:**

No the ID and Name fields are different. 
They are named :
cmbldcoi_child
cmbldcoi_parent

Here is my code:

The change event for the first combobox which makes the other two change:

```
jQuery('#cmbldcoi_language_chain_subj').bind('change', function(){
        var langID = jQuery('#cmbldcoi_language_chain_subj').val();
        if (langID != 0){

            getSubjectCmb_lang(langID, 'cmbldcoi_child', '#div_cmbldcoi_child');
            getSubjectCmb_lang(langID, 'cmbldcoi_parent', '#div_cmbldcoi_parent');


        }
    });
```

}

The function wicht calls the php file to get the info from the database:

```
function getSubjectCmb_lang(langID, cmbName, DivWhereIn){
 var xdate = new Date().getTime();
 var url = 'index.php?option=com_ldadmin&view=ldadmin&format=raw&task=getcmbsubj_lang&langid=' + 
 langID + '&cmbname=' + cmbName + '&'+ xdate;

 jQuery(DivWhereIn).load(url, function(){

 });

 }
```

The PHP code 
 function getcmbsubj_lang(){

```
    $langid  = JRequest::getVar('langid');                    

    if ($langid > 0 ){

        $langid = JRequest::getVar('langid');

    }else{

        $langid = 1;

    }                    

        $cmbName = JRequest::getVar('cmbname');

        //$lang_sufx  = self::get_#__sufx($langid);


    print ld_html::ld_create_cmb_html($cmbName, '#__ldcoi_subjects','id', 'subject_name', " WHERE id_language={$langid} ORDER BY subject_name" );


    }
```

There is a class wich is called ld_html wich has an funnction in it that creates a combobox.
    ld_html::ld_create_cmb_html()
It gets an table name, id field, namefield and optional an where clause.

It all works fine if there is just one combobox thats needs updating. It give a problem when there are two.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your two selectboxes have the same id `#ldlinksubjects` and thus they could fail randomly or both don't work at all. Could you be more expressive, or give complete JS code ?